# npm bin param throwing an unexpected error

Tags: node.js, npm, module

I'm trying to create an `npm` package called `loca-mapper` and for some reason it doesn't run when I include in my scripts: `map: loca-mapper` and launch `npm run map`, but it behaves correctly if you:

- cd `node_modules/loca-mapper`
- `npm i` (after all some dependencies won't be there due to the auto-resolve)
- node `./index.js`

What i get is an error message as follows:

```
/Users/{USER}/{PATH_TO_PROJECT}/node_modules/.bin/loca-mapper: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/{USER}/{PATH_TO_PROJECT}/node_modules/.bin/loca-mapper: line 1: `const { getData } = require("./getLanguages/getLanguages.js");'
```

The content of my `index.js` is structured like this:

```js
const { getData } = require("./getLanguages/getLanguages.js");
const { getConfig } = require("./utils/getConfig");

getData(getConfig());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the beginning of the file would solve the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { getData } = require("./getLanguages/getLanguages.js");
const { getConfig } = require("./utils/getConfig");

getData(getConfig());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).